# vue-cli-service: Is there a way to pass -p parameter to typescript compiler or linter using vue-cli-service?

Tags: vue.js, tslint, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a vue-cli 3 based project. Here is the `include` section of my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue"
    ]
}
```

The typescript linter also uses the same file. I need `yarn lint` command to also lint the files in `tests` directory. When I add the `tests` directory to above `include` section, then `vue-cli-service lint` works as expected but `vue-cli-service build` starts to complain about unknown global functions (`describe()`, `test()` etc).

I created a separate `tsconfig.lint.json` that includes both `src` and `tests` directories and changed the `yarn lint` to actually do a `tslint -p tsconfig.lint.json` (instead of `vue-cli-service lint`). Now both `yarn lint` and `yarn build` work. But `yarn lint` fails when it is invoked from `lint-staged` script.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? All I need is:

1. `yarn lint` should lint both `src` and `tests` directories.
2. When doing a git commit the `yarn lint` should lint staged files in both the directories.